# jQuery.next on a text snippet with no selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here's some example code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="send-notice" name="send-notice" value="1" /> This is a notice to all users.  

<label for="subject">Subject</label>
```

I want to be able to select the text "**This is a notice to all users.**" so I can remove it.

I'm not sure how to do so though.

I've tried using `jQuery('#send-notice').next()`, but that selects the `<label for="subject">` block.

I also tried wrapping a `<div>` around the text using `jQuery('#send-notice').after()` and a closing `</div>` tag on `jQuery("label[for='subject']").before()`.  But jQuery doesn't like unopened elements.

Any help here?

Comment: I know the proper method is to wrap a `<label>` around the text, but I can't.

Comment: consider putting the text in a tag else brute force by the other poster is the way to go....but its really awkward solution.

Comment: Its seems odd to me the browser doesn't store the text as a child node or break it down into a similarly accessible item in the DOM despite there being no tag around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to operate on textnodes, and jQuery steers clear of textnodes. Since you can't wrap the text you want to change in a span or something like that, you can, with some effort, identify the textnodes and do some surgery. This is thrown together quickly, but seems to work:

```
    /* utility function to help us skip whitespace-only nodes */    
    function isWhitespace( thenode ) {
        return !(/[^\t\n\r ]/.test( thenode.data ));
    }   

    /* attach this function to ready() or other trigger */
    function fixtext(){
        $('div#main')
            .contents()
            .filter( function() {
                return !isWhitespace(this) && this.nodeType == 3;
                // nodeType 3 means textNode. Force jQuery to ingest.
            })
            .each( function(){
                $(this).replaceWith( document.createTextNode('Your new text') );
            });
    }
```

This can certainly be reduced and streamlined, but it seems to work using the information in your question, and should give you a starting point on the approach. It doesn't rely on matching your string exactly -- just that the string will be positioned in some larger container (I have it as `div#main` here), and it won't have any non-whitespace siblings. Even if your case is more complex, as long as the text is consistently placed you should be able to identify it within the `filter()` function.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery won't be of too much help here, since its strength is in traversing the DOM, and you don't have a node for it to traverse to here.

I suspect the best you're likely to do is something like...

```
var html = $('#parent-element').html();
html = html.replace("This is a notice to all users", '');
$("#parent-element").html(html);
```

That is: a brute force replacement of the text. Some simple pattern matching could come into play if you want a little protection against the text changing.

```
var html = $('#parent-element').html();
html = html.replace(/<input type="checkbox" id="send-notice" name="send-notice" value="1" />.*?</, '');
$("#parent-element").html(html);
```

Comment: There's a chance that the text could be internationalized, so I would need some pattern matching.

Comment: Hmm... for some reason the pattern matching didn't work for me although logically it looks sound.